# Using Swagger across multiple browsers

Tags: documentation-generation, swagger

Who knows the issue? It seems Swagger cannot support IE. I deployed Swagger example as following in Tomcat. The example works well in Google Chrome & Firefox.
https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/tree/master/samples/no-server

But the example cannot be shown in IE correctly. URL always be directed to tomcat's index page. I have tried to change "localhost" to IP or hostname, but it still cannot work in IE.
Does swagger cannot support IE? Is it a bug?

```
Input the URL and run in IE
http://localhost:8080/swagger/index.html

Redirect to the URL (always insert # inside)
http://localhost:8080/#swagger/index.html
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Swagger's own [petstore demo](http://petstore.swagger.wordnik.com) doesn't seem to work in IE either, so I guess it's a problem with the code rather than with your particular installation.

Comment: I guess that might be the case at the time this comment was written. I can see the petstore demo work fine in IE 8 now.